# Ionic 4 modal backdrop dismiss

Tags: ionic4

I want to disable modal dismiss when you click outside the modal. I’ve tried many different examples but didn’t work.

> async openExtras(){
>       let modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
>         component: ExtrasPage,
>         cssClass: 'extras'
>       });
>       modal.present();
>     }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add backdropDismiss attribute and set it to false

```
async openExtras(){ 
    let modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({ 
       component: ExtrasPage, 
       backdropDismiss:false,
       cssClass: 'extras' 
    }); 
    modal.present(); 
}
```